# Java String execution in Linux terminal

Tags: java, system, exec, processbuilder

I am using StringBuilder to create a string and then trying to execute the string on Linux terminal. But instead of executing whole command, it executed half command and then terminates it. This is my java code snippet:

```
moteCommand.append("CFLAGS+=-DCC2420_DEF_CHANNEL=1");
moteCommand.append(" ");
moteCommand.append("make telosb install.");
moteCommand.append(moteIdList.get(i).toString());
moteCommand.append(" bsl,");
moteCommand.append(moteAddrList.get(i).toString());
String moteCommand2 = moteCommand.toString();
Process moteProgProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(moteCommand2, null,"/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps/XXX/);
```

It gives me this error: 
Cannot run program "CFLAGS+=-DCC2420_DEF_CHANNEL=1" (in directory "/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps/xxx"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

I don't understand why system process is trying to execute only half of the string. Please let me know if anybody knows the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Runtime.exec()`, the characters up to the first space must be the name of the program you want to launch. After that, each "part" between spaces is a separate argument. Note that calling `Runtime.exec()` is completely different from typing a command in bash (or any other shell...) and pressing enter!! If you type a command that works fine in bash, it doesn't mean it will work with `Runtime.exec()`. For example, shell commands (which are not external programs) won't work in `Runtime.exec()`.

What you should do is use `ProcessBuilder`.

Instantiate it, manipulate its `Map` that represents the environment options (ie, the things you are passing *before* the command name, such as the cflags, and anything else you might want), set the command name, give the arguments one at a time (the arguments won't get split at spaces, so you can pass paths containing spaces, for instance), etc. You can manipulate the stdin, stdout and stderr in many different ways (such as: use the same as those used by the Java process; or get instances of InputStream and OutputStream to write to and read from the process; or pipe them), and run the process.

Something along the lines:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("make", "telosb", "install" blablablabla);
final Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("CFLAGS", "....your options....");
pb.start(); // take the Process instance, and you will be able to read the output, wait for it to finish, get the exit code, etc
```

Comment: Could you give me example with respect to my code ? Because I already tried to use ProcessBuilder like this and it did not work. ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("CFLAGS+=-DCC2420_DEF_CHANNEL=1", "make", "telosb", "install.0", "bsl,/dev/ttyUSB0");

        moteProgProcess = pb.start();

Comment: You are not doing what I described above, that's why it isn't working. Actually, you are using it exactly in the same way as you use `Runtime.exec()`. Open the JavaDocs for ProcessBuilder and you get a nice example, with environment options, and all: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Note that your "myCommand" is not `CFLAGS.....`, but it is `make`, ie, the name of the process you want to launch. You `CFLAGS...` thing is part of the environment.

Comment: Is this what you are asking me to do ? ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("make", "telosb","install.0","bsl,/dev/ttyUSB0");Map<String,String> env = pb.environment();
        env.put("var1","CFLAGS+=-DCC2420_DEF_CHANNEL=1");pb.directory(new File("/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps/XXX")); Process p1 = pb.start(); ??

Comment: No. You are putting the value "CFLAGS+=-..." on the variable named "var1". What you need is a VARIABLE named CFLAGS.

Comment: Are you talking about this ? ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("make", "telosb","install.0","bsl,/dev/ttyUSB0");Map<String,String> env = pb.environment(); env.put("CFLAGS","-DCC2420_DEF_CHANNEL=1");pb.directory(new File("/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps/XXX")); Process p1 = pb.start();